# Windows 7 configure speakers only gets sound through left speaker

Tags: stereo, mono

So, my desktop computer (Windows7) is hooked up to a (mini) stereo receiver through a 3.5mm jack wire at the back (connected to a single 3.5mm jack AUX IN in the stereo receiver).
The receiver is, in turn, hooked up to the speakers with good, old-fashioned speaker wire (so there are no RCA cables).

Basically, I used to get great sound through all my speakers, those connected to the right channel of the stereo as well as the ones connected to the left channel. Recently, however, the sound only seems to get through on the left side.

When I go to 'configure' the speakers (right clicking the emblem in the task-bar etc...), testing the speakers also only gives sound on the left, the right gives no sound...

How do I get Windows to recognize both left AND right speakers?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it may be a cable problem, rather than a software issue. Try using a different cable to connect your PC to the speaker system. If that still does not fix the problem, test out that the system actually properly works (by plugging it into another device with a phone or something). One thing I've notice on a lot of audio systems is the amplifier tends to get a bit "rusty". I have a  problem with my surround system where certain speakers won't work. the way to fix this is to pup the volume up full on the receiver, and the speakers should jump to life (then you can turn the volume back down).
Try all these three things then get back to me! :)

Comment: Different cable to connect the two: not an option, as there is the one (green 3.5mm jack) output on my desktop and the one 3.5mm jack input on the stereo receiver. New cable could be the solution but would be the last thing I try. Would like to make sure THAT is actually the issue.

Have tried switching the source (desktop, iPod, phone ...), no difference. Especially, since the built-in Realtek software doesn't produce a sound when I test the speakers.

Rustiness isn't an issue, as I've also tried it with a brand new stereo receiver, which still results in only the left channel playing sound

Comment: Sorry if I'm just not understanding you properly, but are you saying you've plugged in an iPod and there is only audio in the left channel or there is audio in both channels?

Comment: Also, try plugging headphones into your PC to check if it is a PC problem. If it is the case, I imagine it'll be hardware related and you should try to use another audio output or purchase a USB audio interfae or soundcard (which you can pick up cheap)

Comment: Yes, plugging in an iPod only results in audio in the left channel, you understood correctly. Sorry for not explaining it clearly ;)
Tried the headphones tip in two ways:
- headphones connected to the computer = no problem (audio in two channels)
- headphones connected to stereo receiver (which is still connected to the desktop with the 2x 3.5mm jack) = very weak audio in the right channel (hardly audible), which tells me that it's most probably the 3.5mm jack cable causing the issue.
Will get a new one to see if that fixes it, thanks for helping me reach this conclusion!

Comment: Welcome! Did you say that the jack in question is built into the receiver? It is possible to replace those with a YouTube video and a screwdriver! :)

Comment: No it's not, just a 3.5mm jack male to male cable with a single output on my desktop and a single input on the receiver.

Comment: is it a TRS jack? [tip-ring-sleeve] i.e. stereo, or just a TS [tip sleeve] i.e. mono. In other words does it have 2 metal sections plus a tip, or less - or even more, like a composite headphone/mic cable? The green socket needs a simple TRS. [& -1 for suggesting slamming the speakers with full volume to scare it into working.] I'd suggest contact cleaner, Maplins/Radio Shack etc rather than risk bursting the cones

Comment: Tetsujin, I can honestly tell you that has worked for me with various systems. The amplifier can start to not work properly, and a quick boost to full volume usually gets it to work until you turn it off again.

Comment: I hope your speakers are cheaper than mine, then. It's one of the simplest ways of tearing the cones or distorting the voice coils. Wouldn't do your ears much good either on a hefty amp.

Comment: Well, that's a fair point, and I guess I was exaggerating a little. Full volume isn't usually needed. I usually have to do it on my surround system, and the max volume on that doesn't use all of the amp's power (huge overhead to stop the amp exploding) and the speakers in question can take much more power than "full volume", so it's not really a worry to me.

Comment: btw, I'm a sound-engineer by trade… The speakers in my work-room are integral bi-amped 400w units, capable of 118dB sustained SPL [the manufacturers don't quote the peak] see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure Doing that would not only damage the cones & coils, but wouldn't do the windows much good either ;-) Joking aside, I still do not recommend it, when you can get contact cleaner for a fiver.

Comment: That's very true ;)